# textview does not display text (one text view push another far away from the screen)

Tags: android, textview

Now textview shows the statement if i will scroll far away to the bottom. Looks like promis textview become to large. Is there a way to fix it?

[image: screenshot]
everything under stars is part of promis textview. It is a single string with several newline characters
[image: screenshot2] another screenshot

code that generate promises

```
prm = doc.getElementsByTagName("promise");
            for (int j = 0; j < prm.getLength(); j++) {
                prom += parser.getValue(e, KEY_PROMISES, j) + "\n";

            }
            prom.substring(0,prom.lastIndexOf('\n'));
```

layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget32"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/face"
            android:layout_width="68dp"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="243dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/face"
            android:text="from" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/office"
            android:layout_width="242dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/face"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/name"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/face"
            android:text="subject" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top"
        android:numStars="6"
        android:singleLine="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/promises"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ratingBar1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/promises"
        android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/statement"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity for my app

```
public class SingleMenuItemActivity  extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.candidate);
        Log.d("here ?", "No ");
        int loader = R.drawable.loader;
        // getting intent data
        Intent in = getIntent();
        Log.d("here ?", "No ");
        // Get XML values from previous intent
        String name = in.getStringExtra("name");
        Log.d("Name ", name);
        Log.d("here ?", "No ");
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        Log.d("here ?", "No ");
        Candidate p = db.getCandidate(name);
        Log.d("Did i take candidate? ", "yea ");
        db.close();
        Log.d("Statement", p.get_statment());
        // Displaying all values on the screen
        TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView lblOffice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.office);
        TextView lblPromise = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.promises);
        TextView lblStatement = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statement);
        ImageView lblFace = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.face);
        RatingBar lblRating = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
        ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(this);
        lblName.setText(p.get_name());
        lblOffice.setText(p.get_office());
        lblPromise.setText(p.get_promises());
        lblStatement.setText(p.get_statment());
        lblRating.setRating(p.get_ranking());
        imgLoader.DisplayImage(p.get_photograph(), loader, lblFace);

    }
}
```

logcat says p.get_statment() has proper value in it

```
12-16 05:07:16.089: D/Statement(279): I strive for the highest standards of appearance and personal grooming.  If, like me, you think that the University's reputation is being dragged down by lecturers who have little or no regard for fashion and are content to wear ill-fitting or patched clothes then vote for me: the stylish choice.
```

reputation is to low to post image %)

Comment: and is it showing some other text, or it is blank, or missing?

Comment: textview statement is complitly blank, alls othere are shown as entended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found solution, besides i dont understand why textview expanded so much i know how to fix it now:)
first of all we need to know number of lines, which string will produce

```
private static int countLines(String str){
           String[] lines = str.split("\r\n|\r|\n");
           return  lines.length;
        }
```

then simply limit textview in the size

```
lblPromise.setMaxLines(countLines(p.get_promises()));
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your RatingBar is covering your `statement` TextView:

```
<RatingBar
    android:layout_above="@+id/statement"
    ... />
```

Perhaps you meant `layout_below`?

Also your `promises` TextView has a very large top margin, it could be pushing the `statement` TextView off the bottom of the screen:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/promises"
    android:layout_marginTop="124dp"
    ... />
```

---

**Addition**
Apparently there are also a number of newline characters at the end of your `promises` TextView. If you cannot remove these character from the source you can use [`trim()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29):

```
prom = prom.trim();
```

Comment: i changed margin to 5 and fixed alignment but still no result

Comment: Hmm, could you post a screenshot? (Have you tried using a ScrollView, to be sure?)

Comment: i tried to put statement in scroll view but i did not resolve th eproblem, so i just undo it.
http://vk.com/photo17601636_293394853 there is screenshot
evrything under rating bar is promise textview

Comment: Comment edits don't update automatically here... Also the image won't load for some reason, could you post it to imgur.com and post the new link?

Comment: To be clear: the text show is your `promises` text? Does it happen to have a lot a newline characters...?

Comment: it has several newline characters but it is a single string

Comment: Sorry I meant on the end, pushing the `statements` TextView off of the screen. I just got your layout to work in my preview, try adding the `+` (plus signs) to each `layout_below` id, as in `android:layout_below="@+id/promises"`. This shouldn't matter in your case, but it made a difference for me...

Comment: I'm almost out of ideas... :( Your ScrollView should be the root layout, with `widget32` as it's child.

Comment: adding scrollview to th etop element almost solve the problem. You was right frome begining that statement is pushed besides screen. Somehow, promis textview makes lots of new lines after last text symbol. I thout that is because newline character, but i put code to extract text before last newline and nothing changed.

to extract usefull text i used prom.substring(0,prom.lastIndexOf('\n'));
where prom is promis string

Comment: You can always use [`trim()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) to remove any white space before and after your String.

Comment: trim() and filters does not helped, but it helped me with another problem  :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems correct.
If the textView with the id *lblStatement* doesn't show the text probably you have a background where you cannot discern the text (so try to change color), or the margin are inadequate for the textview position.

If `p.get_statment()` has the correct value there are no others possible reasons.